# iOS: How to display parameters in response in tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am trying to set up a `UITableView` inside of a `UIViewController`. I am using storyboard. but when running it on the simulator, the tableview does not display any content. Here is what i tried in Xcode:

1) Drag a table view on `UIView`.

2) Connect it's outlets (`dataSource` and `delegate`).

3) I get response from server like:

```
[{"email_id":"adas@faga.gs","id":66,"mobile_no":"1236547895","name":"asad","relation":"dsfs"},{"email_id":"raj@ghj.com","id":67,"mobile_no":"5632145412","name":"raj","relation":"xyz"}]
```

4)Now what i want to do:

In 1st cell i want to display, 
`name:asad mobile:1236547895 email:adas@faga.gs relation:dsfs`

and in 2nd cell, 
`name:raj mobile:5632145412 email:raj@ghj.com relation:xyz`

But i have no idea about how to do this.Please anyone can solve my issue. help will be appreciable.

I do like following way but it's not working.

a) Add a new file to the project, with the `Objective-C` class template. Name it `EmergencyContactCell` and make it a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

b) then in **EmergencyContactCell.h**

```
@interface EmergencyContactCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *name;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *email;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *mobile;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *relation;
```

c) then `MainStoryboard.storyboard`, select the prototypecell and in the Identity Inspector change its class to `EmergencyContactCell`

d) Then connect all outlets

e) I am using AFNetworking to take response from server, when i got response, after that i do like following way:

```
NSArray *ResponseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseObject options: kNilOptions error: nil];

if (ResponseArray.count >0)
{
   menuItems = [ResponseArray mutableCopy];
   [yourTableviewname reloadData];
 }
```

f) and for display it on cell,

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [menuItems count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EmergencyContactCell";

    //static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";
    EmergencyContactCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

   // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];



//    NSDictionary *content = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name:%@, Mobile:%@,  Email:%@,  Relation:%@",content[@"name"],content[@"mobile_no"],content[@"email_id"],content[@"relation"]];
//    


    return cell;
}
```

I'm not getting what to do at last??

Comment: in here you need to do with two methods , 1. how to save your menuItems can you show that code

Comment: 2. you need to create the customcell or programtically create 4 labels

Comment: can you show that code of webservice call method

Comment: What i the problem in both cell you want all four thing name email phone relation. so just create label and add it

Comment: Update my question sir...@Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step-1**

> No need of this

```
NSArray *ResponseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseObject options: kNilOptions error: nil];

NSMutableArray *finalArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *temp in ResponseArray) {
    [finalArray addObject:temp[@"name"]];
}
NSLog(@"%@",finalArray);

if(finalArray != nil && finalArray.count > 0){

    menuItems=[NSArray arrayWithArray:finalArray];
    NSLog(@"menu items: %@",menuItems);


}
else{
    NSLog(@"zero values from server");
}
```

**Simply Do like**

```
 NSArray *ResponseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseObject options: kNilOptions error: nil];

if (ResponseArray.count >0)
{
   menuItems = [ResponseArray mutableCopy];
   [yourTableviewname reloadData];
 }
```

**Step-2**

for your answer continution

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
     NSDictionary *content = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name:%@, Mobile:%@,  Email:%@,  Relation:%@",content[@"name"],content[@"mobile_no"],content[@"email_id"],content[@"relation"]];



    return cell;
}
```

**Updated Answer**

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EmergencyContactCell";


    EmergencyContactCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    NSDictionary *content = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.name.text = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"Name:%@",content[@"name"]];
     cell.email.text = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"email:%@",content[@"email"]];
      cell.mobile.text = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"mobile:%@",content[@"mobile"]];
       cell.relation.text = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"relation:%@",content[@"relation"]];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: you need like this or you want to show the data on seperate labels

Comment: if you need the modification reply here I will modify my answer

Comment: Thank you sir, it works. but it is in one straight line.... How to show in separate labels ?

Comment: @SurajSukale - good and tanx , if you want to show the details in seperate you go for two types . 1. programtically create the 4labels for each  in inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath , 2. see this https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/customize-tableviewcells-with-storyboards

Comment: @SurajSukale - try once if you not get the answer inform me , I will add the answer , all the best

Comment: can you please add answer sir, i tried, but somewhere i having problem. can you? please.. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @SurajSukale - can you update teh question with updated answer

Comment: I updated my question with updated answer, please help me to solve this issue.. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130007/discussion-between-suraj-sukale-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: perfect answer sir.. perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 2 things

After getting response set that into one NSArray. Declare NSArray
    global one. And your code should be like
    `NSArray *arrayPersonalInfo = responseObject; // responseObject is response`
    got from server. Then call `[tableView reloadData];`

Now update your table view methods to

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return arrayPersonalInfo.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    NSDictionary *dictionaryMenu = [arrayPersonalInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // It will save dictionary object of index
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name:%@ Mobile:%@ Email:%@ Relation:%@",[dictionaryMenu valueForKey:@"name"],[dictionaryMenu valueForKey:@"mobile_no"],[dictionaryMenu valueForKey:@"email_id"],[dictionaryMenu valueForKey:@"relation"]];
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

    return cell;
}
```

If needed add other table view methods like 
`heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfSections`

Comment: sir it is in straight line, i how can i show that in separate labels??

Comment: In question you haven't mentioned it so i got confused.
Does that labels have different background colors?

Comment: no, i just want it in 2(more than 2) lines, not in one line.

Comment: So it means your text is not completely visible and its truncating. Right ? Correct if I am wrong.

Comment: So add 

cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

After assigning text.
This will solve your problem and I edited answer with it.

Comment: Thank you for your help sir. :)

Comment: if cell height is smaller than content ,then again will face problem, so make dynamic cell height, after it looks perfect

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer using storyboard, you can actually add a label into a prototype cell, make sure you set the prototype's cellIdentifier correctly to use it in codes. Then set a unique tag to your label. From your codes you can call viewWithTag from your cell's contentView to get the label and edit it's text property.